# How to configure postgresql to run FastAPI tests in BitBucket Pipelines

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, bitbucket-pipelines, fastapi

I'm trying to set up pipelines for a FastAPI boilerplate that I am working on. What I have so far failed and I can't figure out why.  Here's what I have:

`bitbucket-pipelines.yml`

```
image: python:3.7.4-slim-buster

options:
    max-time: 5

definitions: 
    steps:
        - step: &test
            name: test
            script:
                - >-
                    docker build -f {{cookiecutter.app_name}}/{{cookiecutter.service_name}}/tests.dockerfile
                    -t boilerplate ./{{cookiecutter.app_name}}/{{cookiecutter.service_name}}
                - >-
                    docker run --env POSTGRES_HOST=host.docker.internal 
                    --add-host host.docker.internal:$BITBUCKET_DOCKER_HOST_INTERNAL boilerplate
                    /bin/bash -c /run-tests.sh
            services:
                - docker
                - postgres
            caches:
                - docker
    services: 
        postgres: 
            image: postgres
            environment:
                POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD: trust

pipelines:
    pull-requests:
        '**':
            - step: *test
```

I'm connecting to my database with:

```
DATABASE_URL = os.getenv('DATABASE_URL', 'postgresql://postgres@localhost/postgres')
```

Here's the error I got when I ran the pipeline:

```
E   sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (psycopg2.OperationalError) could not connect to server: Connection refused
E       Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and acceptingE    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
E   
E   (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/13/e3q8)
```

I added `postgresql://postgres@localhost/postgres` because that's how BitBucket sets up postgresql for a default user. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on what I found in [this article](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Bitbucket-articles/Changes-to-make-your-containers-more-secure-on-Bitbucket/ba-p/998464), here's a snippet:

*If you need to communicate from a service running in docker to a service running in your build container, when starting the service provide it the following host entry using --add-host host.docker.internal:$BITBUCKET_DOCKER_HOST_INTERNAL you can then access the service using host.docker.internal:port*

I was supposed to specify `host.docker.internal` as my host:

```
DATABASE_URL = os.getenv('DATABASE_URL', 'postgresql://postgres@host.docker.internal/postgres')
```

instead of using `localhost`

Another approach would be to do the following:

```
DATABASE_URL = os.getenv('DATABASE_URL')
```

then instead of doing `docker run --env POSTGRES_HOS=host.docker.internal`, just do:

```
definitions: 
    steps:
        - step: &test
            name: test
            script:
                ...
                ...
                - >-
                    docker run --env DATABASE_URL=postgresql://postgres@host.docker.internal/postgres 
                    --add-host host.docker.internal:$BITBUCKET_DOCKER_HOST_INTERNAL boilerplate
                    /bin/bash -c /run-tests.sh
```